# Permissions for Group members to have pushed notifications or Timeline Posts

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Not sure if i am asking this correctly, but here it goes.

If you have a group with 150 people on, and not all contribute, they are unlikely to be aware of anything new without looking on the side bar for a number, if any, of new posts.  Is there a way to push a notification if a poll is placed and prompt them to visit.  Or is there a way to post on their time-line.  I cannot seem to find the documentation on what permissions for a group provide once accepted into that group ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question but it sounds like you want to force a notification when posting something to a group via the API? that's not possible - users set their own notification options for groups

Comment: @lgy Sort of right, not so much when someone posts, but at intermittent times.  If as you can get a list of members with their ID's, I am wondering how I could contact all the members so how to inform them of an update?

Comment: You can't unless they're users of your app (in which case send them a notification) - there's no channel that lets app-initiated content reach non-users of the app. You could ask an existing user of the app to send them user-to-user requests or something